# По условию сцепить диапазон ячеек

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть таблица.

```
|  A  |  B  |
|-----|-----|
|  1  |  B  |
|  2  |  A  |
|  1  |  C  |
|  2  |  E  |
|-----|-----|
```

Нужно в ячейку C1 (предположим) выписать через запятую значения из столбца B, где в столбце А стоит единица. То есть, получить:

```
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
|-----|-----|-----|
|  1  |  B  | B, C|
|  2  |  A  |     |
|  1  |  C  |     |
|  2  |  E  |     |
|-----|-----|-----|
```

Comment: В электронных таблицах всегда сложность испытываю при работе с коллекциями ._. Прям темный лес.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть удобная функция FILTER. Для примера из вопроса подойдет формула:

```
=JOIN(", ",FILTER(B:B,A:A=1))
```

Comment: Ларец не сложно открывался. Нашел на англоязычной версии сайта, но оставлю здесь для других пользователей.

Answer (score 1):

```
=JOIN("/";FILTER(B2:B;ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A=1)))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]